# Estimates of kernel function of Schrodinger Operator concerning Littlewood Paley projection operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, dispersive-pde

Maybe this problem is difficult to understand, because we lump integration and distribution together(usually we can distinguish them).

I have some trouble about the following proof concerning the estimate of kernel function of cutoff Schrodinger operators.

Suppose that $P_{N}$ is the classical Littlewood-Paley cutoff operators. $\phi(\xi)$ is the standard bump function. We have the estimates
\begin{equation}
\Big|P_{N}e^{it\Delta}(x,y)\Big|\lesssim_{m}\begin{cases}|t|^{-\frac{d}{2}}, {\rm when} |x-y|\sim N|t|\geq N^{-1},\\ \frac{N^{d}}{\langle N^{2}t\rangle^{m}\langle N|x-y|\rangle^{m}} \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Proof:
\begin{align}\Big(P_{N}e^{it\Delta}\Big)(x,y)&\simeq\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}e^{i(x-y)\cdot\xi}\phi(\frac{\xi}{N})e^{-i|\xi|^{2}t}d\xi\\&=N^{d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}e^{-iN^{2}|\xi|^{2}t+i(x-y)\cdot N\xi}\phi(\xi)d\xi\\&\simeq\Big[N^{d}\hat{\phi}(N\cdot)*(4\pi it)^{-\frac{d}{2}}e^{\frac{i|\cdot|^{2}}{4t}}\Big](x-y)\end{align}
Then we always have the estimates
$$\Big(P_{N}e^{it\Delta}\Big)(x,y)\lesssim \min\{|t|^{-\frac{d}{2}},N^{d}\},$$ Then we can get the final estimate in the domain
$$\{(x,y):|x-y|\sim N|t|\geq N^{-1}\},$$$$\{(x,y):|x-y|\sim N|t|\leq N^{-1}\},$$ and $$\{(x,y):|x-y|\leq N^{-1}, N|t|\leq N^{-1}\}.$$

But for $|x-y|\not\sim N|t|$. Because the boundness of support of $\phi(\xi)$, we can easily see that $|x-y|\gg N|t||\xi|$ or $|x-y|\ll N|t||\xi|$ for $\xi\in{\rm supp}\phi$. By direct calculation, Let $$\Phi(\xi)=-N^{2}t|\xi|^{2}+N(x-y)\cdot\xi$$ we can get $$\nabla_{\xi}\Phi=-2N^{2}t\xi+N(x-y),$$ $$\nabla^{2}_{\xi}\Phi=-2dN^{2}tI_{d\times d}.$$ Construct $$L(D)f=\frac{[Ni(x-y)-2iN^{2}\xi t]\cdot\nabla_{\xi}}{|N(x-y)-2N^{2}\xi t|^{2}}f, \  |\xi|\sim1$$ thus we have $$L(D)^{m}e^{Ni(x-y)\cdot\xi-iN^{2}|\xi|^{2} t}=e^{Ni(x-y)\cdot\xi-iN^{2}|\xi|^{2} t}.$$ Note that
\begin{align}\Big|\Big(P_{N}e^{it\Delta}\Big)(x,y)\Big|&\lesssim N^{d}\Big|\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}e^{Ni(x-y)\cdot\xi-iN^{2}|\xi|^{2} t}L^{*}(D)^{2m}\phi(\xi)d\xi \Big|\\&\lesssim\frac{N^{d}}{|N(x-y)-2N^{2}\xi t|^{2m}}.\end{align}

**The first question is**: Why $|L^{*}(D)^{2m}\phi(\xi)|\lesssim \frac{1}{|N(x-y)-2N^{2}\xi t|^{2m}}$? when doing calculus we find that $L^{*}(D)\phi(\xi)=\nabla_{\xi}\cdot\Big(\frac{Ni(x-y)-2iN^{2}\xi t}{|N(x-y)-2N^{2}\xi t|^{2}}\phi(\xi)\Big)$ which should $\lesssim \frac{N^{2}t}{|N(x-y)-2N^{2}\xi t|}$ so $|L^{*}(D)^{2m}\phi(\xi)|\lesssim \frac{N^{4m}t^{2m}}{|N(x-y)-2N^{2}\xi t|^{2m}}$, where does $N^{4m}t^{2m}$ go??

**The second question is** Why $\frac{N^{d}}{|N(x-y)-2N^{2}\xi t|^{2m}}\lesssim \frac{N^{d}}{\langle N^{2}t\rangle^{m}\langle N|x-y|\rangle^{m}} $? Does it come from that $|x-y|\gg N|t||\xi|$ or $|x-y|\ll N|t||\xi|$? What is the detail of the proof?

**The third question is**  where can I find the material concerning this estimate, any paper?

Thank you!!! Any hint is welcome, God will bless us!

Comment: This might be an ignorant question from me but what does $\lesssim$ mean here? By that I mean: I remember it means $\cdots \leq C \cdots$ for some constant $C$ (but I could be wrong), yet which variables should the constant be, well, constant in regards to? It's for your first question, in case the extra factor can be "put" in the constant of the inequality.

Comment: You are right, $\lesssim$ means that $\dots\leq C\dots$

Comment: In addition $\lesssim_{m}$ in my assertion means $\dots\leq C(m)\dots$

Comment: @BrunoB thank you for your comments

Comment: In your expressions of the form $e^{it\Delta}...$, I believe it should say $e^{it\Delta}\widehat\phi$? As in, you are applying the propagator to a function, and the function is missing from the notation

Comment: Where?@AlexOrtiz